# I hosted a moviepy app, and faced a problem with fonts

Tags: python, imagemagick, vps, moviepy, ubuntu-22.04

I'm hosting on an Ubuntu 22.04, but I get this error when trying to use a TextClip,
convert: unable to read font `Courier' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/1024. convert: delegate library support not built-in 'Courier' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/2108. convert: no decode delegate for this image format` ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/746.
convert: no images defined `PNG32:/tmp/tmpwmbzo9z6.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3362.

If anyone could help, it would be so good!

I tried changing the font, adding more fonts, using default font, but everytime, I face the same problem noted before.

Comment: Install Courier font in your system